Would it make sense performance wise to use workerpool for websocket client to parse incomming messages?
Iam trying to understand how to make node ws client more performant and I have come across worker threads and workerpool. The use case is to parse incomming messages (done in the worker) and pass the result back to main file where the WS connection (client) is opened. Should this perform better than usuall parsing in the main thread?
Websocket message listener:
const pool = workerpool.pool(__dirname + '/messageWorker.js', { maxWorkers: 8 });

    socket.onmessage = (event) => {
        pool.exec('processMessage', [event.data])
            .then((res) => {
                if (res) {
                    // process res
                }
            })
    };

processMessage is function in the worker file in which the message is parsed, res is returned if desired.

Spawning a worker and send  data back and forth is overhead. The quesiton "Should this perform better than usuall parsing in the main thread" depends on what you are doing/trying to solve. Parsing a message should not consume any high resources. Add more details what kind of parsing you are doing/how much data.

@Marc parsing few lines of JSON string data with JSON.parse() each message, read few values and react accordingly to some of them. I guess Iam looking at it from wrong point of view to speed up things.
